# Risk of Not Upgrading to Mint 20.1

Tags: linux-mint, security, upgrade

I am running Linux Mint 18.3 and am quite happy with it. I know that there are newer releases, but 18.3 does what I ask it to do, and that is all I want from my OS. The problem is that support for 18.3 ends in a [few months](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php), which means no more security updates. Those security updates are the only reason I really feel the need to upgrade to Mint 20.1. On the other hand, Linux has a reputation of superb security and upgrading your OS sounds like a really [difficult process](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-20.html) that I am 100% certain I will mess up.

I want to get a sense of how dangerous it would be to not upgrade. If someone said "Using an unsupported OS is common and you have nothing to worry about," I would believe them. On the other hand, if someone said "If you go 6 months without a virus you should buy a lottery ticket," I would also believe them. Without at least an intuitive understanding of the risks involved, there is no possible way for me to make an informed decision. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The question looks like it may be closed as asking for opinion. However before upgrading (whenever that is) re-factor your system to have a separate `/home` partition, and keep it that way. It will make upgrades easier.

Comment: I was worried about it being closed for that reason. I feel like it is objective though, since probability of infection is a measurable quality. If I was asking "Should I upgrade or not", then it would be subjective. However, I am asking "What is the value of this objective factor that I am going to take into consideration when making a decision to upgrade or not", so I would argue that it should be allowed.

Still, thanks for the advice about /home.

Comment: The problem is that while "probability of infection" is a measurable quantity, it depends on your actual network setting and possible attack scenarios. The assessment of what is a possible scenario and how likely it is, however, is again subjective. If the security aspect is your primary concern, you should proabaly ask the question on [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade now or at any time before your distro support ends. There's very little you could mess up with and in case you're afraid, backup your data (actually **do** backups regularly).

You **must** upgrade if either of these is true:

- You use any applications accessing remote resources (e.g. web browser)
- You have network services which can be accessed by untrusted actors (e.g. web server, CIFS server, FTP server, etc.)
- Your system is connected to any LAN/WAN where there can be untrusted devices.